# GraphQL rate limit?

Tags: connect-api, graphql

can anyone help me understand GraphQL rate limit how i can check in my org
not able to understand below limit.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/graphql/guide/rate-limit.html

Comment: Are you trying to hit via POSTMAN? What error are you getting in response?

Comment: As per doco it is the same as `Connect API` so think 1000 request per hour